# C++ makefile failed

Tags: c++, makefile, cygwin

I am learning OpenGL and GLUT recently. I programmed a simple program. This program runs very well in Visual Studio. But when I tried to use makefile to run it. It failed.

[image]

when I click the .exe file, it shows the following

[image]

In addition, My computer is Windows system. I run the program in my friend's computer, it works fine. His computer is MAC system.

My program has 3 files, paint.cpp, library.cpp, library.h
I hope someone can help me solve this. thanks
Here is my makefile

```
LDFLAGS = -lGL -lGLU -lglut
CFLAGS=-g -Wall -std=c++11
CC=g++
EXEEXT=
RM=rm

# Windows (cygwin)
ifeq "$(OS)" "Windows_NT"
    EXEEXT=.exe #on windows applications must have .exe extension
    RM=del #rm command for windows powershell
    LDFLAGS = -lfreeglut -lglu32 -lopengl32
else
    # OS X
    OS := $(shell uname)
    ifeq ($(OS), Darwin)
            LDFLAGS = -framework Carbon -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT
    endif
endif

PROGRAM_NAME= Paint

run: $(PROGRAM_NAME)
    ./$(PROGRAM_NAME)$(EXEEXT)

$(PROGRAM_NAME): paint.o    library.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
    $(RM) *.o $(PROGRAM_NAME)$(EXEEXT)
```

Comment: Does "g++ -o Paint ..." on Windows output a file "Paint" or "Paint.exe"? (If you have both, check timestamps!) Does Windows CMD recognize "./Paint.exe" as executing a file in the current directory?

Comment: Windows definitely is confused - it thinks your EXE is a DLL (?!).